# Need to find out orders less than 10000 where clause is showing incorrect

Tags: sql

My query

```
select round(sum(priceEach * quantityOrdered)) as roundedAmount, orderLineNumber
from orderdetails
where round(sum(priceEach * quantityOrdered)) < 100000
group by orderLineNumber
order by roundedAmount;
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add some data to your code

Answer (score -1):

To filter an aggregated set (**GROUP BY**) you need to use **HAVING** instead of **WHERE**

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(priceeach * quantityordered)) AS roundedamount, orderlinenumber
    FROM orderdetails
    GROUP BY orderlinenumber
    HAVING ROUND(SUM(priceeach * quantityordered)) < 100000
    ORDER BY roundedamount;
```